# Why do only Functions with inline typing detect extra fields?

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I was under the impression that these functions although written a different way had the same exact type signature;
ie

```
type Test = {
  a: number
}
type Fu = (a: number) => Test

var foo1: (a: number) => Test = a => ({ a }) // aka var foo1: Fu = a => ({ a })
var foo2 = (a: number): Test => ({ a })
```

Recently I discovered that one of them allows extra field to be passed in

```
var foo1: (a: number) => Test = a => ({ a, b:1}) // NO error!
var foo2 = (a: number): Test => ({ a, b:2 }) // 'b' does not exist
```

Why is this? is this a bug or limitation of TS?

Sometimes I cannot type the function inline (ie genertics, overides, callbacks) Is there another way to defined them so it always acts like foo2?

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8BQUoEMBcUAdgK4C2ARhAE4YC+GGAbjlVAGYD2HAjAQBT4iZSlQCUKAHywESVDklQ+aXFFqimLdlwBMKRYJIVqognEQKlKtRgD0NqAEt4jgCYRCwBwGMcAGyjAHFAMzKycPPwGwsYKZrIqyFKWOAA0UOR43NahWhy6qAIEhiIm0uaJisqp6QS61hhAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript does do excess property checking for object literals, but only when an object literal is used in a context where its type is specified. When an object literal appears in a context where its type is inferred, then there is no specified type to check it against.

In the expression `(a: number): Test => ({a, b: 2})`, the return type annotation `: Test` specifies what type the object literal should be, so Typescript does excess property checking.

In the assignment `var foo1: (a: number) => Test = a => ({a, b: 1})`, the right-hand side is a function whose type is inferred as `(a: number) => {a: number, b: number}`, which is a perfectly sensible function type. There's no type annotation on the function itself, so the object literal is used to infer the function's return type, rather than the function's return type used to check the object literal. Then there is no error because the function type is assignable to `foo1`'s type (as function types are covariant in their return types).

I'm not sure what an appropriate workaround would be, but that is the explanation for why it happens, anyway.

Comment: Not that I don't appreciate your answer ( Thank you ) I would love to know if there is a work around. Do you know if there is an issue open on github?

Comment: I think if you posted it as an issue, there's a fair chance it would be closed as "won't fix" or "working as intended", because the function on the right hand side is assignable to the type on the left. In your use-case, will the function always simply return an object literal without doing anything else?

Comment: Yea, but there has to be a way to type a callback as an argument in a function such that It would catch extra fields, no?

Comment: One option is to write an identity function like `function test(t: Test): Test { return t; }`, and then the arrow function `a => test({ a, b: 2 })` will warn about the excess property because the `test` function is checking the object literal against the argument type `Test`.